# Backbone.js attribute / fetching seems to work funny

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So, I have the following code that access my rest api:

```
Employees.Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/employee'
})
var daryl = new Employees.Employee({id:17})

daryl.fetch()
console.log(daryl.attributes)
```

Now, when I console.log the attributes, the daryl object is set up like this roughly:

```
daryl = {
  attributes: 
    [0]: {
    id: 17,
    first: 'Daryl',
    last: 'xxxx',
    email: 'xxx'
    },
    id: 17,
    watchers...
    protos...
 }
```

So trying to daryl.get('first') results in undefined.  Everything else is stored in the object in the array at index 0.  Why is this? I'm a newbie here but this is definitely not how most of the tutorials seem to show how backbone works.

So if I do daryl.get('first'), I get undefined.  daryl.get('id') works as expected.  daryl.get('0') actually returns a plain old javascript object of the actual model, i.e. what I would probably expect to be my backbone model to ACTUALLY be.  why is this?

Comment: What does the response JSON look like?

Comment: [{"id":17,"first":"Daryl","last":"Kranec","email":"dkranec@gmail.com"}]

Is having it in an array faulty if it's only one?

Comment: That's your problem, you need to remove the leading `[` and trailing `]` from the response. You're sending down an array with a single object in it, you should only be sending the object.

Comment: Is that really the proper way to do it?  So I only return an array if it's more than one object?  Oof My poorly made mistake.  I almost put the response in the first post but another post I read said you should always return an array to keep it uniform.  I had an eerie feeling though.  Mind posting an answer so I can check it?

Comment: Yes, normally you'd return an array of objects for a collection's fetch, but for a model you'd only return a single object. I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server appears to be returning an array in its response, hence why calling `model.get('0')` is returning the attributes you really wanted. You either need to modify the server's response to only return the object (instead of an object inside an array) or you need to add a `parse` method to your model to return the first item in the response array.

Comment: At the time you wrote your reply asking about my server's response, I was actually looking into writing a parse method at that point in time too..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the issue in question (but doing `console.log` after calling fetch is problematic), but it is important to keep in mind that `daryl.fetch()`is happening asynchronously.

That is to say, you should try:

```
daryl.fetch().done(function(){
  console.log(daryl.attributes);
  model.get("first");
});
```

or

```
daryl.fetch({success : function(model){
  console.log(model);
  model.get("first");
}});
```

This ensures that the AJAX request was complete prior to trying to act on the model and very well maybe why `get` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @dkran, it might be if the timing is right, but it wont be all the time unless you place your code in a callback as I discussed.

Comment: I used your code, changing the second line also to console.log(model.get("first"));  Which resulted in undefined.  The first console.log shows the populated model that console.log(daryl) would have shown previously.  Thanks for the quick fetch lesson though.  Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I've updated my description to show the problem more specific since this doesn't seem to be related to my issue.